# MySQL two table dump, merge, between two instances

Tags: mysql, merge, dump

Is there a method for comparing data between 2 tables between 2 database instances and then merging them? 
So there was everything in both.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql you can select data between table that are in different datababase  simply using a query as :

```
  select A.col1, B.col1
  from databaseA.tableA as A
  inner join databaseB.tableB as B  on A.colkey1 = b.colkey1
```

for merge you can use `JOIN` or `UNION` depending by you needs

and last you can use a `INSERT SELECT` for populate the table you need

Answer (score 0):

If your table schemas are the same, you can just take a dump of one and do a simple `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE <your key clash logic>` to the other.